# How to retrieve data from msw mock request body

Tags: reactjs, msw

I am trying to retrieve data from a mock api call using msw while using Typescript. How would I go about doing this? I keep receiving "Property 'email' does not exist on type 'DefaultBodyType'"

Handler

```
export const handlers: RestHandler[] = [
  rest.post(`/${API_VERSION}/authentication/login`, (req, res, ctx) => {
    const {email} = req.body;
    console.log();
    return res(
      ctx.status(200),
      ctx.json({
        token: "abdb23231232jdsaWEDwdxaCDA",
        expiresIn: 100000,
        isEnabled: true,
        isLocked: false,
      })
    );
  })
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the handler itself some types, describing what the request body and response body should look like.

```js
interface LoginRequestBody {
  email: string;
}

interface LoginResponseBody {
  token: string,
  expiresIn: number;
  isEnabled: boolean;
  isLocked: boolean,
}

export const handlers = [
  rest.post<LoginRequestBody, LoginResponseBody>(`/${API_VERSION}/authentication/login`, (req, res, ctx) => {
    const {email} = req.body;
    console.log();
    return res(
      ctx.status(200),
      ctx.json({
        token: "abdb23231232jdsaWEDwdxaCDA",
        expiresIn: 100000,
        isEnabled: true,
        isLocked: false,
      })
    );
  })
];
```

You also don't need `RestHandler[]` as it's inferred.

[This article](https://dev.to/kettanaito/type-safe-api-mocking-with-mock-service-worker-and-typescript-21bf) written by the MSW maintainer may help understand more about types as well.

Comment: Thank for replying and the link to article! I will upvote and mark this as a justifiable answer as well! I actually upgrade the version of msw and I guess since many people had the same issue, they added a req.json function that returned the values for you without having to do Type-safety while testing. This however does work as well so I appreciate your efforts as well!

Comment: Glad to hear. Going with your very own types certainly has benefits, even when it comes to mocked data.